# C++: "Upgrading" pointer type of subclass member

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Let's say I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A {
    int x;
};

class B : public A {
    float y;
};

class Foo {
    A* obj;
};

class Bar : public Foo {
    B* obj; // I want this to override "obj" in the superclass!
};
```

I'm aware that `Bar` will shadow the `obj` of the superclass `Foo`, and that actually `Bar` will have two fields. But what I really want is that, if some code is able to see an object of type `Bar*`, they may also assume its pointer `obj` is referring to a type `B`. How can I accomplish this?

I've thought of two ways:

1. Add a template to `Foo`, which specifies the type of its pointer. Then, have `Bar` override as `Bar : public Foo<B>`. This adds templates and may be ugly.
2. Make the members protected, add getters in `Bar` which cast `obj` to `B*`, and make sure (in constructors, setters, etc.) that `obj` is only ever set to a `B*` type. This is inelegant because it's not really compile-time and requires a cast.

Are there better solutions available, that don't have the disadvantages of the above?

Thanks!

Comment: From which point you want to edit the `obj` of `Foo`?

Comment: Go with the derived-class specific getter (and cast). The real problem is initialization, not access, because for initialization you will probably want derived class specific initialization of the member in the topmost base class. For that you may want to introduce a third hierarchy of classes, namely factories for the A/B... classes, so that you can pass such a factory up the constructor call chain.

Comment: *"I want this to override "obj" in the superclass!*" - Just to be clear, do you mean in the unposted, mystery code that is some member function of `Foo` , when using the identifier `obj` you want it to refer to `Bar::obj` if the instance being managed is actually a `Bar` ?  Given what is already posted, if there is some `Bar *p`, then `p->obj` will already access the correct `obj` (in fact, you need to class-qualify to `p->Foo::obj` to get to the base-class member). Or are you saying given some `A* p`, you want `p->obj` to refer to `Bar::obj` if `p` is really pointing to a `Bar` ?

Comment: "_This adds templates and may be ugly._" How is it ugly to use templates? Don't they provide whatever you want, by providing you ability to change the type of `obj` at compile time?

Comment: You might want to ponder two questions   (1)   is `A` polymorphic?    (2)   if not, is there any benefit in what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing:

```
class A {
    int x;
};

class B : public A {
    float y;
};

class Foo {
protected:
    A* obj;
};

class Bar : public Foo {
    B* obj; // I want this to override "obj" in the superclass!

public:
    void edit_foo_obj(A* n_obj) {
        Foo::obj = n_obj;
    }

    void edit_bar_obj(B* n_obj) {
        this->obj = n_obj;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    A a;
    B ba;

    b.edit_bar_obj(&ba);
    b.edit_foo_obj(&a);

    return 0;
}
```